# File upload from Angular 6 to Core Web Api hosted on Local IIS not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, image-uploading

I'm currently working on an Angular 6 app with a Asp.Net Core (2.1) Web Api project. My goal is to upload a file from the Angular front-end to the web api. Everything is working locally (testing via running through the IDE). But when I tried uploading both Angular app and Web Api on Local IIS, everything works except for the upload feature. Below is the error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:60/api/xxx/xxx?params=x: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:61' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

CORS is already configured on my web api.

Any ideas what causes this problem?

Comment: Are you sure CORS is configured for production environment as well?

Comment: @AntonToshik It's okay now. Problem solved. I just needed to give permission to the **IIS_IUSRS** for the folder I need access to on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Asp.Net, but if you are seeing that error, then CORS is not set up properly on the server side.

The fact that the response code was a 500 indicates that the server side code may have had a problem processing the OPTIONS request from the browser, and throwing an error of some sort.

The only way to know for sure is to debug it.

A common error when dealing with CORS requests is to forget that the browser is going to send two requests: first, an OPTIONS request without any authentication header, followed by the actual request (GET, POST, etc.) with the authentication header, but if and only if a matching Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is returned on the response to the OPTIONS request.

If your .NET code is trying to inspect the Authentication header on the OPTIONS request, it's not going to find one. Perhaps you're getting a null-pointer exception, or whatever you call that in .NET?

Comment: It's okay now. I just solved the problem just now. All I need was to give permission to the **IIS_IUSRS** for the folder I need access to on IIS. Thanks for commenting by the way.